# Frank's Refusal Of Number One Observatory Circle

Tags: character, analysis, house-of-cards

Why don't the Underwoods move to Number One Observatory Circle -- the official residence of the Vice President of the United States -- when Frank is selected as Vice President? Why does he deliberately insist living in his Washington residence even though he is genuinely irritated by all the renovations the Secret Service and others do due to his refusal?

Comment: Most likely because the cost of a new set for fairly limited use would be too big a strain on the production budget.

Answer (score 1):

Though it's not stated outright anywhere, I assume it's because it would be much harder to orchestrate his plans if he wasn't at his home.

This theory is weakened somewhat when you learn be moved into the white house when he became president, but I think it still hold up. As president, it is potentially much easier to gain privacy, and much, much stranger if you keep your current residence (as the president is under heavier scrutiny than the vice president)